# Is there a problem with Range.Calculate method in Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use range.calculate in excel VBA to limit time taken recalculating a workbook.  However, while the code executes the cell I am trying to calculate never updates.

My code is

```
Sub Test()
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For n = 1 To 1000
    [B8] = n
    [B17].Calculate
    ThisWorkook.Sheets("Output").Cells(n, 1) = n
    ThisWorkook.Sheets("Output").Cells(n, 2) = [B17]
Next n

End Sub
```

The cell B17 contains a sum of a short range on the same sheet.

If I calculate the whole sheet rather than a single cell it works fine, but takes a long time.  This behavior is not the result I expected from the documentation.  Is there a work-around or any guide on how to make range.calculate behave as documented?

Other things tried are:  [B17].Dirty makes no difference.  The calulation does work if I put a different formula in B17, for example Rand().

Comment: Try adding `[B17].Dirty` before `[B17].Calculate` [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.dirty)

Comment: What formula is in B17?

Comment: @Tim. Thanks for the comment. I have added replies to the question.

Comment: @CPD. I had tried using Dirty but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I put '=RAND()' in [B17] of the active sheet which is not "Output". As result of Test execution [Output!B1:B1000] is filled by random numbers. It means that Excel works as expected.

Consider what [B17] will not be recalculated while all of references in its formula is unchanged. During Test execution [A1:B1000] are only cells are changed. If [B17] doesn't refer any of these cells it will not be recalculated (except some functions like RAND used).